# I'm trying to use Rshiny app in google colab it is not working

Tags: r, shiny, google-colaboratory

I want use Rshiny in google colab, I got the following output

"Listening on [http://127.0.0.1:3520"](http://127.0.0.1:3520%22)
But I can't able to use access the above link.

```
install.packages("shiny")
install.packages("shiny", version = "latest")
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        textInput("name", "Enter your name:"),
        actionButton("submit", "Submit")
      ),
      mainPanel(
        textOutput("greeting")
      )
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$greeting <- renderText({
      paste("Hello, ", input$name, "!")
    })
  }
)
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: You would need to create a tunnel first to access Shiny running in Colab.  It **might** work with ngrok + pyngrok  + reticulate when using R kernel in Colab, but if you just want to try Shiny without installing R, you can start with a free account at https://posit.cloud/